# How is there a paradox in the halting problem when you can trace it and it's very clearly non-halting?

Tags: recursion, halting-problem

Here's Alan Turing's halting problem in pseudocode:

```
function halts(f: Function, input: any): boolean {
  // Some logic that can supposedly solve the halting problem
  // ...
}

// A function that takes itself as an argument and does the opposite of what halts says
function paradox(f: Function, input: any) {
  if (halts(f, input)) {
    while (true) {}
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

halts(paradox, paradox); // returns false
```

In line 1 of `paradox`, we have to detether or not `paradox` is halting.  However, `halts` will also recognize that we're attempting to call `paradox` with `paradox` as a parameter, therefore invoking infinite recursion, therefore `paradox` is non-halting.

Where's the problem?

Comment: Why do you say `halts will also recognize that we're attempting to call paradox with paradox as a parameter`? `halts` is generic function that decides the halting problem, we don't care **how** this is done. Notice that `halts` always returns either true or false and cannot run forever (otherwise it wouldn't decide the halting problem).  Now either halts reports that  `paradox(paradox)` halts, but (by definition of `paradox`) this is absurd since, in this case, the `while(true) {}'  line reached, or `halts` reports `paradox(paradox)` as non halting, but then you can check that it halts.

Comment: to expand on Steven's comment, if someone did invent a halting decider, it *wouldn't* actually call the function it was analyzing. It would analyze the source code using some algorithm. There is no recursion `halts(func, input)` would not call `func(input)`. (If you try to invent a halting decider that does call it, well, now you know why that won't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, `halts` will also recognize that we're attempting to call paradox with paradox as a parameter, therefore invoking infinite recursion

You seem to have a particular implementation of `halts` in mind. Also, your reasoning is not correct even assuming that implementation.

Remember that the proof works for *any* possible implementation, it doesn't matter what the actual implementation is.

As for where your reasoning is incorrect, you seem to think that if `halts` can check for a function calling itself, then that means it will detect an infinite loop. This is not the case. There are many functions that do not infinite loop when calling themselves; for example

```
function foo(x):
    if x == foo:
        print "Called foo on input foo!"
    return
```

Additionally, `halts` cannot just look into the implementation to see whether `paradox(paradox)` infinite loops, because if it does so, it will find that the infinite loop `while (true)` is *guarded* by a call to `halts(paradox, paradox)`. So, there is no trivial implementation of halts that works here. Indeed, the whole point of Turing's proof is to show that no such implementation of `halts` exists.

---

P.S.: You have a typo in your pseudocode. The paradoxical function should only take one argument and call it on itself:

```
function paradox(f: Function) {
  if (halts(f, f)) {
    while (true) {}
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```